# biblatex: extract fields without starting a page

Tags: biblatex, page-breaking

I'm trying to extract some data from bib entries for further processing. Sadly if I use a cite command it starts a page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\gettitle}
 {}
 {\gdef\currenttitle{\thefield{title}}}%
 {}{}


\begin{document}
abc
\clearpage
\gettitle{gillies}%
\end{document}
```

That's a problem as it leads to empty pages in my real document (which involves includepdf). Has someone an idea how I could get the data without interfering with the shipout?

## Edit

I'm sorry about the confusion with the `\gdef`: I simply used some senseless code which normally wouldn't start a page. The `\sbox` in is an idea but in my actual code I have additionally an `\includepdf` in the code so I don't want to throw away everything, I only want to prevent the starting code to start a page so that the following `\includepdf` (which uses one of the fields as file name) doesn't force an empty page.

Egreg's reference to `\leavevmode` lead to the solution

```
 {\makeatletter
  \let\blx@leavevmode\relax\let\blx@leavevmode@cite\relax
  \gettitle{gillies}}
```

(`\blx@leavevmode@cite` is executed very early so there is no way to incorporate the code in the definition of `\gettitle`).

Another idea is `\AtBeginShipoutDiscard` from the `atbegshi` package:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\gettitle}
 {\AtBeginShipoutNext{%
  \AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
 {\gdef\currenttitle{\thefield{title}}}%
 {}{}
```

This would remove the need of some wrapper command to hide the leavevmode changes. But I don't know how to check if the page was started by the `\leavevmode` of the cite command (and so can be discarded) or if there is some "normal" text on the page.

Comment: It's not at all necessary to define `\gettitle` with `\DeclareCiteCommand`: use it for an auxiliary macro and define a wrapper `\gettitle` that calls the auxiliary macro in a discarded box and then the other code. You're only looking for complications.

Comment: @egreg: The neat thing with commands defined with `\DeclareCiteCommand` is that they have easy access to all the fields of a bibentry, that they can loop and that they know useful test commands. E.g. in the loopcode I can use code like `\includepdf{\thefield{url}}` and tests like `\iffieldundef`. So I can easily write a cite command which includes a lot of pdf's with `\citepdf{a,b,c,d}`. I would like to avoid to have to write my own "get and store the values" and "loop through the keys" code and use the existing code of biblatex if possible.

Answer (score 12):

A cite command issues `\leavevmode`; evaluate the cite command in a box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\gettitle}
 {}
 {\protected@xdef\currenttitle{\thefield{title}}}%
 {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
abc
\clearpage
\sbox0{\gettitle{gillies}}
\end{document}
```

I used `\protected@xdef` rather than `\gdef`, the reason should be obvious.

Indeed, if I add `\show\currenttitle` before `\end{document}` the answer is

```
> \currenttitle=macro:
->\thefield {title}.
```

if `\gdef` is used (which is obvious). If `\currenttitle` is used, an error is raised:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\currenttitle ->\thefield
                          {title}
```

If `\protected@xdef` is used, the output on the terminal is

```
> \currenttitle=macro:
->Herder and the Preparation of Goethe's Idea of World Literature.
```

which probably is the expected result, because we expand `\thefield` when it *has* a meaning, using the current reference key.

A macro around the `\sbox0` would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\gettitle@aux}
 {}
 {\protected@xdef\currenttitle{\thefield{title}}}%
 {}{}
\newcommand\gettitle[1]{{\sbox0{\gettitle@aux{#1}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
abc
\clearpage
\gettitle{gillies}
\end{document}
```

The additional braces keep `\gettitle` from possibly interfering with macros using `\box0`.

Comment: Please can you explain the difference between `\gdef` and `xdef`? It is not obvious for me ...

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! I added some comments as edit in my question.